# Getting "Unable to evaluate expression" Error, when using Entity Framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I'm using Entity Framework for accessing my database, and I want to get a single row (or let's say the whole table) with the following Code:

```
using (var db = new dbContext())
{
    var user= (from o in db.AspNetUsers
                where o.Email == "email@domain.tld"
                select o).FirstOrDefault();

    var userList = db.AspNetUsers.ToList();
}
```

But when I add a breakpoint after these two queries, there is only the "Unable to evaluate expression" Error, or a List of these Errors stored in my `user` and `userList`. I'm stuck, and can't figure out, why this happens.

I did some research already, and some say it could be the "Code Optimization" of Visual Studio. But I thought, that the Code is not optimized, when you start the App in Debug Mode. Also, I haven't found the option to deactivate the code optimization yet.

Comment: does the code throw if you run the application, or do you just see the error in the debugger?

Comment: I just see the Error in the Debugger, but i get some null value errors later, because the variables above are not filled with data.

Comment: `FirstOrDefault()` returns null when there was no item matching the predicate in the result set, are you sure there is a user with the given email? as for userList, this cannot possibly be assigned null, since `ToList()` cannot return null.

Comment: Yep, the email is correct, I'm sure. It also happens, when i compare integer ID's. It does not fill null at all, I just see the Error, when I step through the Code, and watch the variables. If I want to access them later, it says it holds (a) null value(s). The List is filled with multiple "Unable to evaluate expression" Errors, so later I have a List of null values.

Comment: Try adding .ToList() before .FirstOrDefault(), the toList will execute the query.

Comment: It's hard to say more without more info about your context config, your entities and what line of code is throwing. Not being able to see your objects in the debugger is sometimes normal, since the query might not have been executed yet (that doesn't happen until you enumerate the collection)

Comment: But shouldnt the query has been executed, when I step over the statement?  I cant really say where this throws, because the WebApp does not stop the execution, I just see the error when I debug step by step.

Comment: simply saying `var result = db.SomeTable;` only prepares a query, it doesn't actually run it. The query is run when you force the result to materialize, by enumerating it, calling ToList() or some other operation that forces actual reading of the result. if your app does not stop execution, there is no exception thrown (or it is caught). I'm beginning to think your app is working as intended, only that the debugger has some "quirks" when dealing with lazy loading from a database.

Comment: can you show us some code that is either crashing the app or not giving the desired output? disregarding the error messages in the debugger, is there anything about your app that is not working the way you want it to, but you think it should?

Comment: Its often worth running a profiler to see what the SQL being generated is. Then you can run it directly and see if it brings back the results you expect.

Comment: What version of .NET are you on?

Comment: I'm using .NET Version 4.6.1

I'll try to find out whats wrong, when I'm back home, currently I'm at work, and not able to reproduce this strange Errors. Everything works fine here, I'm also starting to think, its some sort of weird Debugger-Behavior. The programm does'nt stop the execution at all, i just didn't receive any data o_O

Comment: did you ever work out what this was? i'm seeing the same thing. i'm sure this used to work.

Answer (score 1):

ok, something's really broken with the debugger expression evaluation wrt. IQueryable.

try quickwatching:

```
db.Table.FirstOrDefault(i => true)      // works
db.Table.FirstOrDefault(i => i.Id == 3) // "The debugger is unable to evaluate this expression"
db.Table.ToList().FirstOrDefault(i => i.Id == 3) // woks
db.Table.ToList().AsQueryable().FirstOrDefault(i => i.Id == 3) // crashes msvcmon.exe !!!
```

I'm pretty sure this is a regression.